# is there something up with my python turtle code that stops it from continuing the stamping?

Tags: python, python-turtle

at the moment i am trying to port a scratch game to python turtle program to make it more sophisticated.

my main problem with the code is that to begin with, the games gravity doesnt work in the slightest, the rendering function to render the blocks dont work, and controlling meat man himself doesnt work.
if someone could help me point out the issue, i could fix it

the original scratch game is the original scratch game is https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/480779617/ and phasing in the block is part of the game to jump to the other blocks

```
import random
import math
#this is the window
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Super Meat Man")
wn.bgcolor("#87ceff")
wn.setup(width=1200, height=600)
wn.tracer(1)
score = -1
#meat man
meat_man = turtle.Turtle()
meat_man.shape("square")
meat_man.penup()
meat_man.goto(-500,200)
turtle.pos()
meat_man.speed(10)
xv = meat_man.xcor()
yv = meat_man.ycor()
xv = xv*0.9
yv = yv*-1
#block meat man stands on
block = turtle.Turtle()
block.color('yellow')
block.shape('square')
block.penup()
block.speed(0)
block.hideturtle()
#random length and height between the blocks
length = random.randint(1, 7)
height = random.randint(2, 6)
#this is the number of blocks rendered at the moment, it changes every render function
block_number = 0
#coordinates cuz i cannot use the direct xcor and ycor in a math statement
block_xcor = block.xcor()
block_ycor = block.ycor()
#this is the list of coordinates i will use for the stamped blocks, to detect if meat man will colide with one of the blocks that was stamped
block_coords_list = set()
#this is the bad block that kills you if you touch it
bad_block = turtle.Turtle()
bad_block.penup()
bad_block.color('red')
bad_block.shape("square")
bad_block.shapesize(5,1200)
bad_block.goto(0, -290)
#the controls
def goright():
    xv = 5*0.9
def goleft():
    xv = -5*0.9
def jump():
    yv = 15-1
wn.onkey(jump, "w")
wn.onkey(goleft, "a")
wn.onkey(goright, "d")
#this is the rendering on the blocks
def render():
    global block_coords_list
    global block_xcor
    global block_ycor
    global score
    #this sets the turtle into the corect position to start rendering
    turtle.clearstamp(block)
    block.showturtle()
    block.goto(-500,-200)
    #this sets the block that meat man will fall ontop of and start the platformer
    block.stamp()
    block_xcor = block_xcor + 20
    #this is the score update, because the render inishiates every new level, so if i start the score at -1, it will render to zero to start
    score = score + 1
    #this its the rendering itself
    while block_number < 25:
        #this is the random chance of length and height for the block to start on
        block_xcor = block_xcor * length * 20
        block_xcor = -500
        block_ycor = block_ycor * height * 20
        block.stamp()
        #this adds the coordinates to the list that compares coordinates
        block_coords_list.add((block_xcor, block_ycor))
#colisions
if meat_man.pos() in block_coords_list:
    yv = 0
if meat_man.pos() == bad_block.pos():
    score = 0
    render()
render()
```

Comment: One good place to start is to practice some debugging skills. These are critical as a programmer. [This article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) has some great tips to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

you did not import turtle you have to import turtle

```
import turtle
```

and it stops because of the "render"

if you take the last line = `render()` it works and finishes